# NOT NULL constraint failed, а почему?

Tags: python, django

Когда я пытаюсь создать суперпользователя

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

я получаю следующую ошибку

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: me_teacher.subject_id
```

me/models

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, AbstractUser
from django.db import models
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from wisdom.models import Subject

class Teacher(AbstractUser):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='teacher_subject',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

wisdom/models

```
from django.db import models

class Subject(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

в чём моя проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо предоставить возможность создания пользователей без привязки к предмету (`null=True`)

```py
    subject = models.ForeignKey(Subject, related_name='teacher_subject',
        null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: Не-а, NOT NULL constraint failed: me_teacher.user_id. Миграции создавал

Comment: Да, и по user то-же самое (не заметил что ошибка изменилась)